# "ByRef argument type mismatch" when passing For Each iteration Object to Function

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

When I am trying to pass a Table object into a separate function I get this `ByRef argument type mismatch` error.

Code where error occurs:

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each OuterTable In doc.Tables
    For Each InnerTable In OuterTable.Tables
        If InStr(InnerTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "SomeString") > 0 Then
            currentCV.AddProject ExtractProjectInfo(InnerTable) ' <- Error here
        End If
    Next InnerTab
Next OuterTable
```

ExtractProjectInfo method:

```
Function ExtractProjectInfo(projTable As Table) As Project
    Dim proj As Project
    Set proj = New Project
    ' Commented out code
    Set ExtractProjectInfo = proj
End Function
```

Passing in any other object works fine, it's just Table that gives this error. I'm assuming I'm missing something really simple here? What's even stranger that this method did work at some point, and I can't remember having changed anything relating to the loop or function.

Comment: This is easily solved. You need to declare `InnerTable` as a `Table`. Put `Dim InnerTable As Table` at the top of the first `Sub` and it works. (Plus change `InnerTab` for `InnerTable`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to change the function declaration to -

`Function ExtractProjectInfo(ByVal projTable As Table) As Project`

OR add this line -

`dim InnerTable as table`

before -

`For Each InnerTable In OuterTable.Tables`

Comment: +1 Both these solutions work fine. I'd prefer the second as it makes the iterator variable explicitly typed. (And who says the OP wants to pass the variable by value and not by reference?!)

Comment: Yes, the second one solves my issue. Kind of a silly problem now that I see the solution.

Comment: Although this technically answers the question, it does nothing to explain _why_. That is because `For Each` considers each element to be a `Variant`, unless the loop variable has already been declared with a more specific type.